# TypeScript: Why can't I access a property on a Union Type which is only defined on one object?

Tags: javascript, typescript, union-types

I want to have either an object with the property `a` which is a number or an object with property `b` which is a string. In plain JavaScript the variable test would be either a number or undefined if the other object has been passed. Why is this an error in TypeScript? Or is there a way to do this without an type guard?

```
function t(aOrB: {a:number} | {b:string}){
    const test: number | undefined = aOrB.a
}
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAhgCgIYHkBOAhALmQG8MCIwBbAIwFMcBfZAHxOoIGcYc4IBzBgEpiwZGORQkXVLS5EKNei2SQAJrRC9aq5AF5k2fADoMwBsCA

Comment: I don't understand the question. The *entire point* of having a static type system is to not have to do those sorts of checks at runtime. Your question is like asking how to bolt a prop on to your jet airplane.

Comment: If I write `const oops = {a: "hello", b: "goodbye"}`, I can call `t(oops)` [with no error in TypeScript](https://tsplay.dev/qWJ26W).  That's the problem with assuming `aOrB.a` is `number | undefined`.  You'd be better off making `aOrB` of type `{a: number, b?: undefined} | {a?: undefined, b: string}`.

Comment: @jcalz this is what i want to achieve, but without the boilerplate :) I think that's still fully statically typed (as you did), but would be nicer without all this extra stuff (which is how JavaScript works by default)

Comment: Can you elaborate? TypeScript "without all this extra stuff" is just JavaScript.  If you want TypeScript to know that reading `aOrB.a` will produce a value of type `number | undefined`, then you need to tell the compiler that somehow.  Object types in TypeScript are not [exact](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936) for good reasons having to do with class/interface hierarchies, so it does not assume that `{a: number} | {b: string}` will have an `a` property of type `number | undefined`, because a value of type `{b: string}` may have some unknown `a` property.

Comment: I'd be happy to help and suggest an answer you're comfortable with if possible... I'm just not sure where you draw the line between "too much boilerplate" and "pure JavaScript".

Comment: For example, would [this](https://tsplay.dev/lWYgdN) work for you, where you say `aOrB: ExclusifyUnion<{a:number} | {b:string}>` and `ExclusifyUnion` is a utility type that automatically turns an "open" union into a "closed" one?  Or do you want to keep `{a: number} | {b: string}` and use some other sort of [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types)?

Comment: @jcalz I reread your answer and get the example which is what I actually don't want to allow on the call site (passing ops). Probably therefore it's a justified error. And your solution with the `ExclusifyUnion` is exactly what I wanted. Thank you! In my case I still need the open union at a few spots but when I want the solve my described problem I can use the `ExclusifyUnion`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a check on `if ('a' in aOrB)` and `if ('b' in aOrB)` before returning.

Answer (score -2):

you can use **typeOf** like this

```js
function t(aOrB:any){
const test =((typeof(aOrB) == "object")?aOrB.a:aOrB);

console.log(test);
}
t({a:123});
t(123)
```